# How to multiply values in a list using java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is there a sum() equivalent method in stream which can perform multiplication of values given in a stream?

I've a list of Integers like this :

```
List<Integer> listOfIntegers = new ArrayList<>();
listOfIntegers.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,4,2,7,5));
```

I'm able to get the sum of all the integers, but unable to find an API which can multiply the values and give the output.

```
listOfIntegers.stream().mapToInt(a -> a).sum();
```

If I try to use forEach to do it, then I cannot store the result as only final variables are allowed to be used inside it.

Is there any alternative to this?

Comment: Have a look into this link you probably will get your answer.
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/78484/multiplying-corresponding-integers-using-streams

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Try reduce of streams, it should help.

Like:

```
listOfIntegers.stream().reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b)
```

This [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html#reduce) provides more information on how to use reduce.

Comment: Of course, there is no need to box the values first: `IntStream.of(1,4,2,7,5).reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b)`

Comment: If you're fine with getting an `Optional`, then you can drop the first argument to `reduce`.

Answer (score 50):

One thing to keep in mind when multiplying an unknown number of `ints` is the possibility of overflows.  Rather than `(a,b) -> a*b`, it is safer to use `Math::multiplyExact`, which will throw an exception on overflow:

```
listOfIntegers.stream().mapToInt(x->x).reduce(1, Math::multiplyExact);
```

Alternatively, you can accommodate large results by reducing on `BigInteger`:

```
listOfIntegers.stream()
    .map(BigInteger::valueOf)
    .reduce(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger::multiply);
```

Reduction with an identity will return `1` or `BigInteger.ONE` if the list is empty, which may not be what you want.  If you wish to handle the case of an empty list, remove the first argument to `reduce` and then deal with the resulting `Optional`.

Answer (score 1):

I **contribute to @Misha answer** because of I have found an example where we would want use BigInteger rather than primitive datatypes for multiplication.

I was solving this kata: [Numbers with this digit inside](https://www.codewars.com/kata/numbers-with-this-digit-inside/train/java), where we are given x: an int and d: a digit. We need to find the numbers from 1 to x which contain d, and return its count, sum and multiplication as a long array.

First I tried the following code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Kata
{
  public static long[] NumbersWithDigitInside(long x, long d)
  {
    if(d > x) return new long[3];
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = 1; i <= x; i++){
      String current = String.valueOf(i);
      if(current.contains(String.valueOf(d))){
        list.add(i);  
      }
    }
    return new long[]{list.size(),
                list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum(),
                list.stream().reduce(1, (a,b) -> a*b)};
  }
}
```

When we execute the following tests:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;

public class SolutionTest {
    @Test
    public void BasicTests() {            
        assertArrayEquals(new long[] { 0, 0, 0 }, Kata.NumbersWithDigitInside(5, 6));        
        assertArrayEquals(new long[] { 1, 6, 6 }, Kata.NumbersWithDigitInside(7, 6));        
        assertArrayEquals(new long[] { 3, 22, 110 }, Kata.NumbersWithDigitInside(11, 1));        
        assertArrayEquals(new long[] { 2, 30, 200 }, Kata.NumbersWithDigitInside(20, 0));        
        assertArrayEquals(new long[] { 9, 286, 5955146588160L }, Kata.NumbersWithDigitInside(44, 4));
    }
}
```

It outputs:

```
arrays first differed at element [2]; expected:<5955146588160> but was:<-1973051392>
```

Because of it fails when attempting the last test case:

```
assertArrayEquals(new long[] { 9, 286, 5955146588160L }, Kata.NumbersWithDigitInside(44, 4));
```

So to check if it was due to an overflown I replaced:

```
list.stream().reduce(1, (a,b) -> a*b)};
```

With:

```
list.stream().mapToInt(num->num).reduce(1, Math::multiplyExact)};
```

So then, it outputs:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: integer overflow
```

Finally I used BigInteger as follows:

```
list.stream().map(BigInteger::valueOf).reduce(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger::multiply).longValue()}
```

Being the complete code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.BigInteger; 

public class Kata
{
  public static long[] NumbersWithDigitInside(long x, long d)
  {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = 1; i <= x; i++){
      String current = String.valueOf(i);
      if(current.contains(String.valueOf(d))){
        list.add(i);  
      }
    }

    if(list.size() == 0) return new long[3];

    return new long[]{list.size(),
                list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum(),
                list.stream().map(BigInteger::valueOf).reduce(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger::multiply).longValue()};
  }
}
```

➡️ For further information:

[BigInteger class](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/biginteger-class-in-java/)
[longValue()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/biginteger-longvalue-method-in-java/)

Answer (score 1):

And here is an example for decimal products:

```java
// Some list
List<Double> values;
...
double product = values.stream()
    .reduce(1.0, (acc, value) -> acc * value)
    .doubleValue();
```